# Fazer um subset com uma mesma condição em diferentes bases no R

Tags: r, for

Estou querendo aplicar uma mesma condição de `subset` em diferentes bases no R.
Pensei que o `for` fosse resolver, mas não obtive sucesso.

Segue programação utilizada:

```
for(i in c("mar16", "jun16", "set16", "dez16", "mar17")){
 postos[i]<-subset(postos[i],postos[i]$SEGMENTO=="Bancos")
}
```

Tem como usar o `for` para esse tipo de situação?

Comment: seria interessante você disponibilizar uma parte do seu banco de dados para reproduzirmos o seu código.

Comment: É possível, porém há formas com menor custo para fazer o que precisa. Acredito que teu código esteja com dois erros,o primeiro é salvar na mesma base (o primeiro `postos[i]`), o segundo é o que está te gerando mais problemas, não tem o `[i]` no último `postos`. Observe que seu resultado possível é um dataframe com apenas uma coluna.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar as funcões `lapply` e `split`.

Ex: `lapply(split(postos, postos$SEGMENTO), i).`